# C++ console program crashes without any error

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve problem 5 of Project Euler, but program crashes and I don't get any error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* Problem 5:
    2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
    What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
*/

int selle(int number) {
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        if (number % i == 0)
            c++;

    return c;
}

int problem(int number) {
    while (number > 0) {

        if (selle(number) == 20)
            return number;

        number++;
    }

    return 404;
}

int main() {
    long long number = 2;

    cout << problem(number);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in the "for" loop in the first function, but I don't know what it is. Also trying to set funcions to long long it happens.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are expected to use a Least Common Multiple (LCM) function defined in terms of Euclid's Greatest Common Divisor (GCD).

Comment: FIY, in Windows the program produces an error box "Stopped working". In the old times it used to encourage the user to tell Bill Gates about it. Apparently that created too much work for him, because now it says that Windows is checking for a solution (artificial intelligence, yay!), and then changes to let me either Debug or Close the program.

Comment: French's gcc tells me `Exception en point flottant`!

Answer (score 8):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    if (number % i == 0)
        c++;
```

When `i` is zero (first iteration)...you are dividing by zero...this is not allowed.

That's why your program crashs.

Comment: Glad I could help. If that answered your question, you should vote up and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are performing `number % 0` at some point. Like division by zero, modulo by zero is also not allowed. If the second operand in a modulo operation is 0, it will lead to undefined behaviour (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

By the way, you could start with `long long number = 20;` and perform increments by 20 (`number += 20;`), because you're not gonna find any matches in between.